# Powershell replace a value in XML file

Tags: xml, powershell

I got 2 XML files I'm reading a value from the first and need to replace that value in the second XML in a specific string, this is what I got so far and it doesn't work well it change the whole XML to #document for some reason

**EDIT**
Reworking my whole logic for the script and I'm stuck with trimming the node, getting an error at IdexOf why?

```
<BunnyTemplate> <Parm Name="A-1" Source="Application" OnAbsence="1.com"> <Parm Name="A-2" Source="Application" OnAbsence="2.com"> <Parm Name="A-3" Source="Application" OnAbsence="\\3\3"/> <Parm Name="A-4" Source="Application" OnAbsence="4.com"> </BunnyTemplate>
```

```
$file1 = "C:\..\Desktop\file1.xml"
$file1Content = [xml](Get-Content $file1)
$targetNode = $file1Content.SelectSingleNode("//General/@findMe")
$trimmedNode = $targetNode.Substring(0, $targetNode.IndexOf('last'))
```

Comment: Please show sample xml content of `$file2`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I can't it work related, <something>
</something> looks like that with values inside

Comment: Why not add a sample with dummy values and/or names then?

Comment: <BunnyTemplate>
<Parm Name="Bunny" Source="Bunny" OnAbsence="value-to-replace"/>

</BunnyTemplate> @Remko hope this helps

Comment: In the sample XML you can simply do: `$file1.BunnyTemplate.parm.OnAbsence = 'NewValue'`

Comment: Issue is I got multiple prams like that

Comment: Which is why you need to provide a good and representative example...

Comment: You are right, here is more accurate example ```<BunnyTemplate>
<Parm Name="A-1" Source="Application" OnAbsence="http://1.com"/>
<Parm Name="A-2" Source="Application" OnAbsence="https://2.com"/>
<Parm Name="A-3" Source="Application" OnAbsence="\\3\3"/>
<Parm Name="A-4" Source="Application" OnAbsence="ftp://4.com"/>
</BunnyTemplate>```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `-replace` on an XML document, use `XPath` instead.

Assuming `$file2` contains:

```xml
<BunnyTemplate>
  <Parm Name="Bunny" Source="Bunny" OnAbsence="value-to-replace"/>
</BunnyTemplate>
```

... you could do the following:

```bsh
$file2Xml = [xml](Get-Content $file2)

# Locate target node
$targetNode = $file2Xml.SelectSingleNode("//Parm[@OnAbsence]")

# Overwrite attribute value
$targetNode.SetAttribute('OnAbsence', "text${trimmedNode}")

# save file
$file2Xml.Save("C:\path\to\output.xml")
```

`SelectSingleNode("//Parm[@OnAbsence]")` will return the first `<Parm>` node that has an `OnAbsence` attribute.

If you specifically need to target one with `Source="Bunny"`, you could use `//Parm[@Source = 'Bunny']` instead

Comment: Thanks for the quick replay, I'm not sure how I should use the xpath could you provide an example?

Comment: @BugsBunny You're already using XPath to retrieve the value from `$file1`! If you update your question with a sample of `$file2` I can show you, just redact any company-specific values

Comment: @BugsBunny Updated the answer

Comment: Hmm idk what went wrong but now if I try to Get-Content from the XML file and write-host it I don't get anything but no error

Comment: @BugsBunny again, it's hard to say without knowing the xml ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯.

Comment: @BugsBunny please stop posting code in comments. [Edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61733229/edit) and add a sample for _both files_